# laravel 5 using oauth2-server-laravel how to create client in oauth_clients table?

Tags: rest, laravel, oauth-2.0, oauth2-server

I am using the `PasswordGrant`, It's require client_id and client_secret params to generate access_token.

But how to create a new client for a App ?

Just make a new `REST-ful API` and insert it to database when App first launch?

Is this a right way to do that?

thanks.

Comment: Typically the client would already exist in the database and user authenticates themselves with a specific client. You don't want to have a new client record in the database for every user that authenticates themselves with your application.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to insert into the table oauth_clients

```
DB::table('oauth_clients')->insert([
 'id' => the_id,
 'secret' => the_secret,
 'name' => the_name
]);
```

I hope you find it useful